# How to pull a private GitHub repository (organisation) with node.js

Tags: node.js, github, pull, organization

I have a private GitHub repository that is owned by an organization. I want to pull the repository automatically after pushing to it. The *webhook* is already working, and I receive the event, but now I am stuck at the part where I pull the repository.

###### *How can I pull a private GitHub repository, that is owned by an organization, using a single command, or using a package.*

I have done research on this subject, however, I was unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

(async () => {
   const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('git pull https://<token>@github.com/<username>/your_repo.git', {cwd: '/path/to/your_repo'})
   console.log(stderr, stdout)
})()
```

You can generate a personal access token with clone and pull permission from here:
https://github.com/settings/tokens

Comment: If it fails to find git, you can try referencing git from your bin folder or changing the shell in the options such as {shell: 'powershell.exe'}